# Ansible - specify host or host groups

Tags: ansible

I am trying to be able to specify which severs to deploy to. My playbook declaration looks like this:

```
--- 
- 
  hosts: qa
```

I then have a hosts file which is in the same directory as the playbook.

```
[localhost]
localhost   ansible_connection=local

[qa]
qa1         ansible_ssh_host=52.0.0.1       ansible_ssh_port=22
qa2         ansible_ssh_host=52.0.0.2       ansible_ssh_port=22
```

I am currently running my playbook with: `ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml --ask-vault-pass -e build_number=205`

However this method requires me to change the playbook everytime to deploy to localhost. I tried to change `hosts: qa` to `hosts: {{ hosts }}` then pass hosts=qa or hosts=localhost but I couldn't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to this myself:

```
--- 
- 
  hosts: all
```

Then when you run from command line you can add the parameters: `--limit localhost` or `limit=qa`

Answer (score 1):

### Ansible variables

Change your playbook to this:

```
---
-
 hosts: {{ hosts }}
```

And run your command with extra variables

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml --extra-vars "hosts=localhost build_number=205" --ask-vault-pass
```

[Source](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line)

### Environment variables

For environment variables your playbook should look like this:

```
---
-
 hosts: {{ lookup('env','ANSIBLE_HOSTS') }}
```

Specify it for `localhost` with `export ANSIBLE_HOSTS=localhost`.

### Shell variables

To use variables for just one command (with the playbook from environment variables) type the following command:

```
ANSIBLE_HOSTS=localhost ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml --ask-vault-pass -e build_number=205
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the full issue. I want to be able to change the group of servers from the command line. e.g. ansible-playbook -i hosts/qa playbook.yml --ask-vault-pass -e build_number=205 or similar

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to do it avoiding env variables?

Comment: I found the answer I was hoping for `--limit localhost` or `--limit qa`

Comment: put that up as an answer for others :)